# Django JSONField is not able to encode smileys properly

Tags: python, mysql, django

I plan to store a dict in a Django `JSONField`. One key of this dict is a comment a user can enter. And users like a lot to add some smileys in their comments...

The problem is that some smileys, are saved properly in DB.
The database is MySQL 8.0.31, Django version is 4.0.8 : `JSONField` is supported for this environment as reported in documentation. The database default encoding is **utf8mb4** and collation **utf8mb4_general_ci**.

With that model :

```
class TestJSONField(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
```

Here is the test case :

```
comment=b'smiley : \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'.decode()
t=TestJSONField(pk=1, data={'comment':comment})
t.save()
r=TestJSONField.objects.get(pk=1)
print('BEFORE :', comment)
print('AFTER :', r.data['comment'], '(str)')
print('AFTER :', r.data['comment'].encode(), '(utf-8 encoded bytes)')

which gives :

BEFORE : smiley : 
AFTER : smiley : ? (str)
AFTER : b'smiley : ?' (utf-8 encoded bytes)
```

As you can see the smiley is not stored correctly.
This smiley is 4 bytes encoded, this may be the source of the problem because with 2-bytes encoded chars I do not have any problem.

With a `TextField` and using json `dumps()/loads()` I do not have any problem.

Do you have an idea how to have 4 bytes encoded smileys to be saved in a `JSONField` ?

Comment: Please run and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE char%';`

Answer (score 0):

The database settings was utf8mb4, the tables were also the same, but not the columns that were in utf8mb3. After altering columns encoding to utf8mb4, everything is going right now.